# How i can change iphone view background ?

Tags: iphone, ios5

I have used this code. However, the view background did not change.

```
UIColor *background = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];
[[self view] setBackgroundColor:background];
[background release];
```

Comment: the above code is working for me

Comment: I suspect you have a nil somewhere, could be the UIImage, or the view itself. Try using [UIColor redColor] as the color to narrow it down.

Answer (score 3):

Try :

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];
```

It'll save your memory to create the background variable.

Comment: This should work.
Additionally make sure that background.png exist.

Comment: Thanks so much , its working now . my problems were 1- image name 2-View drawing Opaque was selected

Answer (score 0):

I suppose u don't have the image .

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIColor *background = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings_Icon_1X.png"]];
    [[self view] setBackgroundColor:background];
    [background release];
}
```

please add the image to the project folder

Comment: did u check the image is der or not

Comment: Thanks so much , its working now . my problems were 1- image name 2-View drawing Opaque was selected (yes) it should be not selected

Comment: both of them are right but the first answer save memory